# laravel 4.1 Redirect::to()

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel 4.1 and study Jeffry Way's course

I had an error in my code due to the explanation on laravel 3 and I'm using 4.1.

```
Route::get('{shortened}', function($shortend) 
{
    // query the DB For the row with that short url 
    $row = Url::where('shortend', '=', $shortend)->first();

    // if not found redirect to home page 
    if (is_null($row) ) return Redirect::to('/');

    // else grab the url and redirect
    return Redirect::to($row->url);
```

and the error is:

> keep looping to main page not to the site

Here is my full routes.php file

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello'); 
});

Route::post('/', function()
{
    $url = Input::get('url');
    $record = Url::where('urls', '=', $url)->first();
    if ($record) {
        return View::make('result')
            ->with('shortend', $record->shortend);
    }
    // otherwise add new row and return shortned url 
    // create a results view and present the short url to the usr  
});

Route::get('/sucess', function ()
{
    return View::make('sucess');
});

Route::post('/sucess', function (){
    $done = ' Great data inserted ';
    $site_data = Input::get('data_insert');
    $site = new Url;
    $site->urls = $site_data;
    $site->shortend = 'masts';
    $site->save();
    return $done;
});

Route::get('{shortend}', function ($shortend) 
{
    // query the DB For the row with that short url 
    $row = Url::where('shortend', '=', $shortend)->first();
    // if not found redirect to home page 

    if (is_null($row) ) return Redirect::to('/');
    // else grab the url and redirect 

 });

 Route::get('{url}', function ($url)
 {
     $row = Url::where('urls', '=', $urls)->first();
     return Redirect::to($row->url);
 });
```

The problem is when I return 'message' in else section the code runs perfectly 
and if I tried to redirect it to external page like site.com that I fetch from database 
I got loop.

I tried to make a route for url as above and all I get is a blank page.

Comment: Are your other routes defined above or below this one? You should make sure your other routes are defined above this one, so that they are of a higher priority. If this route is above the others, `'/'` will land inside this route handler and will cause a redirect loop.

Comment: the other routes are above that section of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `DB::where('shortend', $shortend)` 
   is short for 
   `DB::where('shortend', '=', $shortend)`
2. `Route::get('{path?}, ...` catches `'/'` as well with `$shortend` equal to null, thus the query will return null thus it will redirect to itself again.
3. Try to use the same name for the url parameter and the function.

   Route::get('{slug}', function ($slug) {
       // your controller method.
   }

Comming from your Routes file I created one that should more or less work:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello'); 
});

Route::post('/', function (){
    $site = new Url;
    $site->urls = Input::get('url');
    $site->shortened = Str::random(5);
    $site->save();
    return View::make('success')->withSite($site);
});

Route::get('{shortened}', function ($shortened) 
{
    // query the DB For the row with that short url 
    $row = Url::where('shortened', $shortened)->first();
    // if not found redirect to home page 

    if (is_null($row) ) return Redirect::to('/');
    // else grab the url and redirect

    return Redirect::to($row->url); 
});
```

Comment: in this code i have every thing is good like this  

Route::get('{path?}', function($shortend) 
 {

  // query the DB For the row with that short url 

  $row = Url::where('shortend', '=', $shortend)->first();
  

  // if not found redirect to home page 
  if (is_null($row) ) return Redirect::to('/');


  // else grab the url and redirect 
  return 'Done';

but when i put this one 

return Redirect::to($row->url);

i get the loop 
and even when the url graped from DB still loop

Comment: you enter into loop because you enter `Route::get('{path?}'` again again

Comment: you must define route for `url` which you get from database

Comment: i will try that and right now 

thanks for the fast aid and help

Comment: i have add the full route to review by you guys 
i hope that will solve my mistake and make me understand

Comment: okay i had done something and i get result the code is 

  `return Redirect::to($row)->with('url', $row->url);`

[http://url.dev/%7B%22id%22:%226%22,%22urls%22:%22http:%5C/%5C/google.com%22,%22shortend%22:%22masts%22%7D]
and the result come in the Url bar like that

Comment: I took your routes file and created controllers that are simple and easy to understand. I didn't test this, so watch out. All you need to do is create a decent DB scheme and your views.

Comment: Okay @hannesvdvreken i will keep my eyes open thanks for your help amigo

Comment: Thanks @hannesvdvreken its works perfect im so glad for your help